# What do I ask in this if condition?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

I got the following code:

```
if (a & 1){
...
}
```

But when do I go in the if condition? There is no `==` or `!=`. I am very confused...
When do I go in the if condition an when do I not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, any non-zero expression is considered to be true.

Here I got an example for you:

```
int a = 5;
if(a & 1)
{
        printf("hello");
}
else
{
        printf("where am I?");
}
```

You got an integer a which is 5. 5 in binary digits is 0101. And you got 1. 1 in binary digits is 0001.
Now the binary AND operation on those two:

```
    0101
&   0001
_________
    0001
```

Expanation of the AND operation:

```
0 & 0 -> 0;
0 & 1 -> 0;
1 & 0 -> 0;
1 & 1 -> 1;
```

Now we see it. Everytime we have an `1` at the end of our integer (here integer `a = 5`), we get a solution with an `1` at the end.
In C: You step into an if condition, if the condition you ask (here `a & 1`) is `TRUE`. The condition is true if you receive an `1`.
So, everytime you receive an `1` (000000...001 is a 1 as well) you print `"hello"` and if you get anything but an `1` (for example `4 & 1` -> `0100 & 0001 = 0000` -> receive a `0`) you print out `"where am I?"`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!! Finally I got it :-D Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
if (a & 1){
    ...
}
```

It is checking, if **a** is odd or even. **&** is a bitwise AND operator. If **a** is an odd number, then a&1 produce 1 and **a** is an even number, then a&1 produces 0.

Take **a** to binary. Then do AND operation with 1.

AND operation happens like this way:

```
0 & 0 = 0;
0 & 1 = 0;
1 & 0 = 0;
1 & 1 = 1;
```

If **a** is an odd number, then there must be a **1** in LSB of **a**. Otherwise LSB will be 0.

Comment: Umm , no `&` is not logical AND operator , it is bitwise AND operator .

Comment: sorry... mistake .. :)